# Move all files from the partition where Ubuntu installed to another partition

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, partitioning, files

I am a total Linux beginner and I probably messed up a lot during the installation (Already tried reinstalling).

Ubuntu installed all of its files in a partition with very little space, and it keeps saving to it. How can I move it to another partition with more space?

Answer (score 0):

[i.e: move all the files on screen to "New Volume"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfLbt.png)